# How do I get the full URL to an image in Cakephp?

Tags: image, url, cakephp, hyperlink, path

Let's say I have an "image.jpg" stored in the assets folder and the path is "www.example.com/public" and I want only the string path to the image. How do I get this? I do NOT want the html tags only the path string.

Comment: Do you wanna say that the file image.jpg is stored in the path you gave?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: please elaborate your question. Or make it clear

Comment: what do you mean by the `string path to the image`

Comment: If I have an image in the assets folder, how do I get the URL to that image?

Comment: Have you tried $_SERVER global variable's keys???
Check if there is any need in it for you.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I meant the "webroot/img" folder. So the file path would be cakephp/app/webroot/img/image.jpg

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After trying the various CakePHP global constants (ROOT, WEBROOT_DIR, WWW_ROOT, CSS, etc.) with no results, the general solution seems to be found in the $this->webroot property that returns the path to the application webroot. Thus for the various cases above we may have in our layouts, views or elements:

A simple image tag:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/foo.gif" .../ >
```

A background image within a table cell the old way:

```
<td background="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/foo.gif">
```

An input of type="image":

```
<input type="image" src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/go_btn.gif" ... />
```

> ```
> I think webroot always work
> ```

Comment: Worked for me. It's important to note some globals have been deprecated as of 2.4: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

Comment: Note: This solution is not plugin-safe.

Answer (score 9):

Look inside the source code of [`HtmlHelper::image()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.2/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L787) to see how this helper creates the right URL; Slightly modified, this is how it's achieved:

```
$imageUrl = $this->assetUrl('image.jpg', array(
    // note: only required if you need the
    // URL -including- http://example.com
    'fullBase'   => true,
    'pathPrefix' => IMAGES_URL
));
```

The source code for Helper::assetUrl() can be found here: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.2/lib/Cake/View/Helper.php#L305

Answer (score 7):

In CakePHP 3 (from version 3.2.4), you can use the url/image helper,but the path is not necessary:

```
$this->Url->image('image.jpg');
```

Or other assets:

```
// Outputs /js/app.js
$this->Url->script('my.js');

// Outputs /css/app.css
$this->Url->css('my.css');
```

Comment: The question is to have the full url, not if its necessary or not. This is not working, for example, if you need an image in an email. Thats why the option "fullbase" exists.

Answer (score 5):

```
    $imageUrl = $this->Html->assetUrl('image.jpg', array(
        // note: only required if you need the
        // URL -including- http://example.com
        'fullBase'   => true,
        'pathPrefix' => IMAGES_URL
    ));
```

this works even if you are using themes

Comment: Works except I had to use : `'pathPrefix' => Configure::read('App.imageBaseUrl')` because the imageBaseUrl is defined in core.php

Comment: Works in Cake 3.0 alos.
This is the best and most reliable answer for Cakephp. Should be flagged as so.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->Html->url('/img/image.jpg') // returns /cake/app/img/image.jpg
```

Optionally pass `true` to example one for the full base URL. (`mysite.com/cake/app/img/image.jpg`)

```
WWW_ROOT . 'img/image.jpg' // full/path/to/webroot/img/image.jpg
```

Comment: Hey, I'm trying the Html->url but I'm getting the "Call to a member function url() on a non-object" error. I've included "public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');" in my Controller...

Comment: @JohnathanAu what version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: This is a CakePHP helper function which is only available in the View and not the controller. That is the most likely reason you're getting that error.

Comment: You did not specify in the controller. Use `WWW_ROOT . 'path/to/file.jpg'` elsewhere

Comment: Just to add to @Ross's answer, the `WWW_ROOT` is a local path to the server. `$this->Html->url(...)` will generate a URL which is specific to the domain the site is being served from. Oh and it's usually better practice when building local paths to use the `DS` constant instead of using back/forward-slashes because it is platform dependent. Using `DS` means you'll be able to deploy in any environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$this->webroot.'img/abc.jpg'
```

$this->webroot will provide you the current path of your app.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP, normally Images will be stored in webroot/img folder.

This [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html) will be helpful for you.

```
     HtmlHelper::image(string $path, array $options = array())
```

Parameters:

```
     $path (string) – Path to the image.

     $options (array) – An array of html attributes.
```

Hope you find this as useful.

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP version 3, you can use the url helper:

```
$this->Url->build('/img/image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

check for this constant provided by the cakephp 2.0+ `FULL_BASE_URL`

[click here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html) to know all

Comment: note CakePHP : 
Deprecated since version 2.4: This constant is deprecated, you should use Router::fullbaseUrl() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
$this->Html->url('/', true).'img/image.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

As of CakePHP 3.5, I think the best option is :

```
$imgUrl = Cake\Routing\Router('/', true) . 'img/' . $imageName;
```

If your inside a plugin scope, `$this->webroot` doesn't fit.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Example: http://localhost:8080/ninavendas/rhhealth_vendas/pessoa/importar

In cake 3+ you can use : $this->request->webroot

It's return: /ninavendas/rhhealth_vendas/

Answer (score 0):

`fullBase` option - Return **full URL with domain name**:

```
$this->Url->image('image.jpg', ['fullBase'=>true]);
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 3

use Cake\Routing\Router;

```
<img src="<?php echo Router::url('/', true); ?>/img/name.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code...

```
<?php $image = $this->Html->image('../../site/webroot/img/folder_name/'.$content->image_path.''); ?>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to compose the path yourself. If you know the name of the file and the directory to where it resides, what is stopping you from doing the following:

```
$imageUrl = sprintf("%s/%s/%s", FULL_BASE_URL, "public", $imageName);
//  this produces http://www.example.com/public/image.png
```